Intel X710 not detected for Asrock WRX 90 WS EVO
After getting one of those Asrock WRX 90 WS EVO motherboard, the onboard 2x 10Gbps network adapter are not discovered. I used an USB adapter to install the OS and installed the proprietary driver from Intel (i40e), which did not fixed the issue.

The adapter is not detected as a valid Link

ip link show
The Onboard 2x Intel X710 adapter is not shown.

The adapter exists

lshw -C network
*-network:0               
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GBASE-T
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       logical name: /dev/fb1
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1024x768 visual=truecolor xres=1024 yres=768
       resources: iomemory:1480-147f iomemory:1480-147f memory:f4680000-f46fffff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GBASE-T
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:1480-147f iomemory:1480-147f memory:f4600000-f467ffff



Checking driver outputs:
sudo dmesg | grep -e /dev/fb0 -e i40e #replace the device with your adapter local name


[    1.492017] i40e: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection XL710 Network Driver
[    1.492019] i40e: Copyright (c) 2013 - 2019 Intel Corporation.
[    1.492164] i40e 0000:01:00.0: Cannot map registers, bar size 0x0 too small, aborting
[    1.492205] i40e: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -12
[    1.492241] i40e 0000:01:00.1: Cannot map registers, bar size 0x0 too small, aborting
[    1.492268] i40e: probe of 0000:01:00.1 failed with error -12


Half solution
I found an interesting post that claims that enabling SR-IOVon the BIOS resolve the issue. I checked and it effectively works.
However, SR-IOV has some negative side effects, especially with virtualization. I wonder why this error (i40e 0000:01:00.0: Cannot map registers, bar size 0x0 too small, aborting) appears, and how to fix it in a more friendly manner.
The question
Is this an issue most likely a Kernel, motherboard or driver issue? And how to fix it?

You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; if it's a kernel issue you maybe able to switch kernel stacks, but you've not yet told us what you're using, thus we can't know what options you have available.

I have the LTS 6.1.112 kernel. Sorry for missing this information.

You've still not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; however the 6.1 kernel you mention isn't a supported Ubuntu kernel, being chosen instead by Debian who release on the odd year where as Ubuntu release their LTS on the even year. Are you using Ubuntu? as your details imply you're not.
